# Childish or childlike?

Tags: translation, meaning, nuances

This is a two-part question.

First of all, I'm trying to determine the meaning of 「幼児じみた」in the following sentence:

スプーンを四十五度の角度でお碗{わん}にすべりこませ、大きく口を開ける時のマンフレッドのどこか**幼児じみた**仕草{しぐさ}を思い出した。

It seems like it could mean either "childish" or "childlike", but since the former has a negative connotation, I want to make sure I'm understanding the nuance.

Secondly, what exactly is the purpose of 「どこか」just prior to 幼児じみた?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How old is マンフレッド?  That would automatically determine for which meaning 幼児じみた is being used.

Comment: We don't use 子供**らしい** /幼児**らしい** for someone who's not a
 子供/幼児, do we... ↓

Comment: @Chocolate That is what I meant to imply with my comment.

Comment: @l'électeur He is an adult, so I'm guessing that in this case it would imply "childish"?

Answer (score 3):

> > どこか幼児じみた仕草しぐさを思い出した。
>
> It seems like it could mean either "childish" or "childlike", but
>   since the former has a negative connotation, I want to make sure I'm
>   understanding the nuance.
>
> Secondly, what exactly is the purpose of 「どこか」just prior to 幼児じみた?

Yes, the word 幼児じみた means childish and is rather disapproving. Especially, 幼児 is a small child, aged like around two to five.
If it meant approvingly childlike, we have other expressions such as 幼児らしい.

どこか is, as literally means somewhere, used when you can't really pinpoint where it is, but you find something to someone or something. I'd say it's actually closer to somewhat or somehow.